How do I extract map key-values from a json in sumologic?
I've gone through the sumologic documentation but I can't figure out how do I extract map key values from sumo logic. so I've a json that looks like this
{
    "eventType": "DummyEvent",
    "subEventType": {
        "subEventType1": 100,
        "subEventType2": 200,
        "subEventType3": 200,
    }
}

And I published this json as logData key. so I get the exact json, eventType and subEventType in 3 columns when I query sumologic with
_sourcecategory = "event-extractor-dev" "Event Metadata"
| json field=logData "eventType", "subEventType"
| where eventType matches "*"

But I'm struggling to figure out how can I group by based on the map's key value. for example we can have different eventType and subEventType and I want to see how many subEvents are there per eventType. something like this



EventType
Sub EventType
Count




EventType A
Sub Event Type A1
100


EventType A
Sub Event Type A2
200


EventType B
Sub Event Type B1
300


EventType B
Sub Event Type B2
200



I've tried using keyvalue and regex for the sumologic but it's not working
| keyvalue field=subEventType  "*:*" keys.
I've also tried to use regex but it's failing too
| parse regex field=subEventType "\"(?<subEventType>[^\"]+)\":(?<count>\\d+)" multi as subEventType, count
| sum(toLong(count)) as count by eventType, subEventType
| sort by eventType, subEventType

but I'm getting unexpected token 'a' found after the multi. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.
Note: they keys and values inside the map are dynamic.
Update: It was solved with the following regex
parse regex field=subEventType "\"(?<subEventType>[^\"]+)\":\"?(?<count>[0-9]+)\"?(?:,|}|$)" multi


Regex is ALWAYS the wrong tool for JSON. Sumologic supports JSONPath so use that instead. https://help.sumologic.com/docs/search/search-query-language/parse-operators/parse-json-formatted-logs/

@MonkeyZeus, Thanks. I will take a look. I solved the problem by fixing the regex though.
